# Identify wx.BitmapButton created by wxformbuilder

Tags: python, wxformbuilder

I have a little python question. I created a GUI using `wxformbuilder`. In this GUI, there are multiple bitmap buttons. They are all binded to the same function.

In my main program, I want to separate them depending on their name. Obviously my `GetEventObject()` doesn't work here.

I could manually edit the automated GUI code, but i prefer not to do that. Is there any function I could use in order to retrieve lets say the `btn_forwardleft` name from the GUI file?

In my automatic generated gui.py

```
    self.btn_forwardleft = wx.BitmapButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap( u"button_upleft.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.BU_AUTODRAW )
    self.btn_forwardleft.SetBitmapSelected( wx.Bitmap( u"button_upleft_p.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ) )

    self.btn_forwardright = wx.BitmapButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap( u"button_upright.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.BU_AUTODRAW )  
    self.btn_forwardright.SetBitmapSelected( wx.Bitmap( u"button_upright_p.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ) )

    self.btn_forwardleft.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnArrowButtonPress )
    self.btn_forwardright.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnArrowButtonPress )
```

and in my main.py program

```
def OnArrowButtonPress(self,event):
    keyname = event.GetEventObject()
  # print keyname
    timeoutflag = False
    if(keyname=='btn_forwardleft'):
        command = 10
    elif(keyname=='btn_forwardright'):
        command = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetEventObject()` returns pointer, which can be compared with `self.anything` like that

```
def OnArrowButtonPress(self,event):
    keyname = event.GetEventObject()
  # print keyname
    timeoutflag = False
    if(keyname==self.btn_forwardleft):
        command = 10
    elif(keyname==self.btn_forwardright):
        command = 20
```